# Determine Transfer Learning Strategy for NER task

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, transfer-learning, named-entity-recognition

I worked on a Transfer Learning project in which I created a training dataset (labeled) and I used a pre-trained BERT model and fine-tuned it. The project was an NLP project in which I performed customized named entities recognition.
I'm working now on documenting the work so I have to specify which strategy of transfer learning I did.
i found this blog https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-hands-on-guide-to-transfer-learning-with-real-world-applications-in-deep-learning-212bf3b2f27a
but even after reading it I still confused about the strategy and I want to make sure of my choice.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to come up with an abstract entity such as "strategy" - just describe what you have done.

Comment: yeah and that's what I'm doing but after the description and presenting the different transfer learning types I have to say the name of the strategy that I worked with